# WP_query exclude posts of a format

Tags: wp-query

I'm using the code below to try to exclude the format "post-format-quote", but it is excluding all posts, including ones of the standard format (no format).

```
            $myposts = new WP_Query(array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('post-format-quote'),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 3
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tax_query` takes an array of arrays.  Try this:

```
$myposts = new WP_Query(array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array('post-format-quote'),
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                ),
                'posts_per_page' => 3
                )
            );
```

Further reading: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/